# How to export a 3d plot in matplotlib as a video

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, export, mp4

I want to export a 3d plot of matplotlib as a video. I read [this solution](http://import%20numpy%20as%20np%20points%20=%20np.array%20(%5B%5B%5B472.983284,%20114.5,-1792.%5D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B720.65216064,%201535.5,%20-1792.%5D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B1500.20385742,%201535.5,%20-1008.%5D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B1252.39562988,%20114.5,%20-1008.%5D%5D%5D)%20import%20matplotlib.pyplot%20as%20plt%20from%20mpl_toolkits.mplot3d%20import%20Axes3D%20from%20matplotlib.ticker%20import%20(AutoMinorLocator,%20MultipleLocator)%20%25matplotlib%20qt5%20def%20init():%20%20%20%20%20fig%20=%20plt.figure()%20%20%20%20%20ax%20=%20fig.add_subplot%20(111,%20projection=%223d%22)%20%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20points:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20=%20np.array(%5B%5Bi%5B0,0%5D,%20i%5B-1,0%5D%5D,%20%5Bi%5B1,0%5D,%20i%5B2,0%5D%5D%5D)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20y%20=%20np.array(%5B%5Bi%5B0,1%5D,%20i%5B-1,1%5D%5D,%20%5Bi%5B1,1%5D,%20i%5B2,1%5D%5D%5D)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20z%20=%20np.array(%5B%5Bi%5B0,2%5D,%20i%5B-1,2%5D%5D,%20%5Bi%5B1,2%5D,%20i%5B2,2%5D%5D%5D)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ax.plot_surface(x,%20y,%20z)%20%20%20%20%20ax.set_xlabel(%27X%27);%20ax.set_ylabel(%27Y%27);%20ax.set_zlabel(%27Z%27)%20%20%20%20%20return%20fig,%20def%20animate(i):%20%20%20%20%20ax.view_init(elev=10.,%20azim=i)%20%20%20%20%20return%20fig,%20%20#%20Animate%20anim%20=%20animation.FuncAnimation(fig,%20animate,%20init_func=init,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20frames=360,%20interval=20,%20blit=True)%20#%20Save%20anim.save(%27basic_animation.mp4%27,%20fps=30,%20extra_args=%5B%27-vcodec%27,%20%27libx264%27%5D)) but still I could not reach what I want. I want to simply export one complete rotation around the figure (angle from 0 to 360). I tried the following code but it is only giving me several plot views rather than a single video:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.ticker import (AutoMinorLocator, MultipleLocator)
%matplotlib qt5

points = np.array ([[[472.983284, 114.5,-1792.],
        [720.65216064, 1535.5, -1792.],
        [1500.20385742, 1535.5, -1008.],
        [1252.39562988, 114.5, -1008.]]])

def init():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot (111, projection="3d")
    for i in points:
        x = np.array([[i[0,0], i[-1,0]], [i[1,0], i[2,0]]])
        y = np.array([[i[0,1], i[-1,1]], [i[1,1], i[2,1]]])
        z = np.array([[i[0,2], i[-1,2]], [i[1,2], i[2,2]]])
        ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)
    ax.set_xlabel('X'); ax.set_ylabel('Y'); ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    return fig,
def animate(i):
    ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=i)
    return fig,

# Animate
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=360, interval=20, blit=True)
# Save
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

In advance I do appreciate any help.

Comment: the link is fubar

Comment: you're asking the incorrect question. The question should be, how to rotate a plane, because the animation doesn't work.